# Is there a way in elisp to make variable access trigger a function call?

Tags: variables, elisp

I am programming in elisp, and I would like to associate a symbol with a function such that an attempt to access the variable instead calls the function. In particular, I want to trigger a special error message when lisp code attempts to access a certain variable. Is there a way to do this?

Example: suppose I want the variable `current-time` to evaluate to whatever `(current-time-string)` evaluates to at the time the variable is accessed. Is this possible?

Note that I do not control the code that attempts to access the variable, so that code could be compiled, so walking the tree and manually replacing variable accesses with function calls is not really an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the Common Lisp [`define-symbol-macro`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defi_1.htm).

Emacs Lisp lacks this feature, you cannot accomplish what you are trying to do.

However, not all is lost if you just want an error on accessing a variable.
Just [`makunbound`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Void-Variables.html) it and access will error out (unless, of course, someone else nds it first).

Comment: I know I can make the variable unbound to trigger an error, but I wanted to provide a more informative error message about the underlying problem. But I guess this isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that.

As Sam says, `define-symbol-macro` would be the closest thing in Lisp (tho you make it sound like the accesses might be compiled beforehand, in which case even `define-symbol-macro` would be powerless).  The closest thing in Elisp would be `cl-symbol-macrolet`, but that is even more limiting than `define-symbol-macro` since it has to be placed lexically around the accesses.